# PHP cURL function

Tags: php, curl

We have develop a CURL function on our application. This curl function is mainly to map the data over from 1 site to our form-field in our application. 
However, this function has been working fine all the while and ready for use for more than 2 months. Yesterday, this fucntion was broken down. the data from this website is no longer able to map over. We are trying to find out why the problem is. When we troubleshooting, it shows that there is response timeout issue.

To re-ensure there were nothing wrong on our coding and our server performance is working, we have duplicates this instance to another server and try out the function. It was working perfectly.

1. Wondering if any one out there facing such problem?
2. What could the possibility to cause this issue?
3. When we are using cURL, will the site owner know that we are calling their data to map into ours server application? If so, is there a way that we can overcome this?
4. Could be the owner that block our server ip address? tht's why it function works well on my another server but not in the original server?

Appreciate your help on this.

Thank you,

Comment: "response timeout". `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` maybe? http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php look for timeout options

Answer (score 0):

1. Your problem description is far too generic to determine a specific cause. Most likely however there is a specific block in place.
2. For example a firewall rule on the other end, or on your end, would cause all traffic to be dropped, thus causing the timeout. There could also be a regular network outage between both servers, but that's unlikely.
3. Yes, they will see it in their Apache (or IIS) logs regularly. No, you cannot hide from the server logs - it logs all successful requests. You either get the data, or you stay stealthy. Not both.
4. Yes, the webserver logs will contain the IP doing all the requests. Adding a `DROP` rule to the firewall is then a trivial task.

I have applied such a firewall rule to bandwidth and/or data leechers a lot of times in the past few years, although usually I prefer the more resilient `deny from 1.2.3.4` approach in Apache vhost/htaccess. Usually, if you use someone else's facilities, it's nice to ask for proper permission - lessens the chance you get blocked this way.

Answer (score 0):

1. I faced a similar problem some time ago
2. My server IP was blocked from the website owner
3. It can be seen in the server logs. Google Analytics, however, won't see this, as cURL doesn't execute javascript.
4. Try to ping the destination server from the one executing the cURL.

Some advices are:

Use a browser header to mask your request.
If you insist on using this server, you can run trough a proxy.
Put some sleep() between the requests.

Comment: HI, may i know how you overcome this?

Comment: I tried to change IP address and try it, it also cannot... Anyone has any ideas on this? Can advise? We also simulate the problem on the server to use CURL function to get the data of another site on the non working server, it does'nt work too. It shows: Connection timeout.

Comment: Did you try pinging the other servers ?